# Integer solutions of $ y^{2} = 5x^{2} + 17 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, pell-type-equations

Show that there are no integer solutions to the equation 
$$y^{2} = 5x^{2} + 17$$
using your knowledge of modular arithmetic and congruence classes.

**My attempt**:
Take 17 congruence mod 5 and show that it is negative at some point, but $$y^{2}$$can't be negative, so there is a contradiction?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. I would suggest you to explain what did you try to solve the problem, so people can give you hints or a better answer. Good luck!

Comment: Hint: modulo 5.  There are only 5 cases to check.

Comment: @vadim123, do I check the congruence of x^2 mod 5?

Answer (score 7):

Your attempt cannot work, since reducing modulo an integer (here $5$) irreversibly wipes out the distinction between positive an negative numbers; one can never apply arguments based on comparison "less than" after modular reduction.

On the other hand one can argue about algebraic relations after modular reduction. After reduction you get $y^2\equiv 17\equiv 2\pmod5$, and it is not hard to show that there are no solutions for$~y$ in this congruence relation.

Comment: it makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 3):

First rule out $x$ being odd looking at modulo 4. For $x$ even $5x^2$ is going to be a multiple of 10. Now you should be able to proceed.

Comment: i don't get why do we look at modulo 4?

Comment: Anything that works is fine. Normally one starts looking at small modulus and 4 is a good choice. Or you can argue with last digit (mod 10 operation). $5x ^2$ will end with $5$ or $0$ as last digit  and hence RHS will have 2 or 7 as last digit which can never be the last digit of a square.

Comment: that makes sense. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If $y^2=5x^2+17$ then $y^2\equiv_5 17\equiv_5 2$.
But $$(1)^2\equiv_5 1$$ $$(2)^2\equiv_5 -1$$ $$(3)^2\equiv_5 -1$$ $$(4)^2\equiv_5 1$$ $$(5)^2\equiv_5 0$$ So there are no solutions to $y^2\equiv_5 2$, therefore $y^2=5x^5+17$ has no solution.